# using clock() as a thread to time other threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, clock

I am new to scheduling and multi threading in c and am trying to implement 20threads for processing my processes in MLFQ scheduler in C language
I want my 21st thread to be clock thread and time all the arrival, execution and completion time.

How do I make the last thread as clock one? and Is their an easy way to connect last thread to all process threads?

Edit 1. 
for the clock thread : -
21st thread
Accessible by rest of 20 threads so that they can time their arrival, execution, termination, etc.
Clock is just supposed to give time to rest of threads a regular intervals so that they function accordingly

Comment: What is the clock thread supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, read first [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) & [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) & [sched(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html) & [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). Then use [pthread_getcpuclockid(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_getcpuclockid.3.html) and [clock_gettime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html). Remember that the kernel's scheduler can migrate any thread from a CPU to another one at any time!
See also other [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), in particular [sched_setaffinity(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html), 
[pthread_setaffinity_np(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html), [cpuset(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cpuset.7.html), [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Your clock thread might have some event loop using [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)